# invalid syntax while importing mne package in python/Atom

Tags: python, package, python-import

I'd like to know if any of you could help me with this issue.
I am trying to get to use the MNE package in python to analyze EEG data. I run on Linux 18.04.

I installed Atom last version and MNE by PIP + all the scientific packages(numpy,pandas,etc).
I opened Atom and typed:

```py
    import mne
```

Then I ran it and I obtained the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/atom_script_tempfiles/9b375e90-191b-11ea-b755-49276afb2bfa", line 3, in <module>
    import mne
  File "/home/vmh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mne/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .utils import (set_log_level, set_log_file, verbose, set_config,
  File "/home/vmh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mne/utils/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .config import (set_config, get_config, get_config_path, set_cache_dir,
  File "/home/vmh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mne/utils/config.py", line 539
    print(out, end='', file=fid)
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The statement in the last part the traceback `print(out, end='', file=fid)` isn't compatible in python 2.7.

Also from the projects github page (https://github.com/mne-tools/mne-python)

> Note that MNE-Python 0.17 was the last release to support Python 2. MNE-Python 0.18 only works under Python 3, and MNE-Python 0.19 requires Python 3.5 or higher.

Since python 2.7 will be unsupported soon (https://pythonclock.org), I would suggest you update to python 3. If you cannot upgrade to python 3, use MNE version 0.17 instead.

Comment: Great, I was able to solve forcing Atom to run python3. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error is resolved by using python3.